# Increase bit depth of an image in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing

Are there any possible way(s) to increase an image's bit-depth and save extra information of that image  into that increased bits without affacting original pixel values?

- ie: Original image = 24 bits RGB
- Needed : 32 bits (Extra 8 bits to
  store some other information)

Comment: Hard to imagine, if you mean the new data should not be displayed. You could remove it later, though, but if you store image data it will always show. More or less, but 8 bit used will be very very visible.

Comment: Yeah that's my requirement anyways (to represent a list of data inside an image invisibly - not steganography - because i have done embedding  to that image hence later to extract i need the same pixel values.. so can u suggest a way to insert extra information to the image invisibly?

Comment: Well, you can of course convert the image format from 24bpp to 32bpp ARGB and use the alpha channel to store an 8-bit value, but that will be *very* visible when viewing the image!!

Answer (score 0):

**you can try to use alpha channel**

- convert to RGBA
- but different fileformats process it differently
- so it could change the visual appearance while previewing
- try: **TGA,PNG,BMP**
- formats like: **JPG,PCX,..** does not support alpha channels
- also some formats/viewers can choose background color which changes appearance too
- you can partially use lower bit count of alpha to avoid too much noisy previews
- for example `00XXh,80XXh or FFXXh` depends on the blending function
- but if you really need 8 bit per pixel then use format that ignores Alpha channel in your used viewers

**you can add the new information after image**

- some formats like **GIF** use end of file markers
- so you can add your data after that mark ...
- but you need to handle the image load/save your self
- some formats use offset table or starting address of image data inside header information
- you can put your data inside or even in between image data
- and offset the start addresses accordingly
- also for that you need to handle load/save yourself
- booth of this ways will not show additional information in previews
- but viewers and antivirus apps can detect the wrong size
- and poorly written loaders can even crash ...

**you can put the info into auxiliary data/channels of image**

- format like **GIF** have additional data chunks used for subtitles,animation commands, synchronizations and more
- you can encode your data into it
- this way is clean but there are not many file format capable of this
- advanced tools for such files can see the added information but you need to look for it ...